# orthonormality and transpose of vectors

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $ \{u_1, u_2, \ldots , u_k \} $ be $k$ vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Show that  $\{u_1, u_2, \ldots, u_k\}$ is an orthonormal family if and only if the $n \times k$ matrix $U = \begin{bmatrix}
u_1,u_2, \ldots, u_k
\end{bmatrix}$ satisfies the equation $U^{\intercal} U = I_k$, where $I_k$ denotes the $k\times k$ identity matrix.

Can anyone help me prove the statement above?

Comment: What is the entry at position $(i,j)$ of $U^TU$?

Comment: thank you for your comment guys, I'll take a closer look at the problem.

Comment: Not quite a duplicate—that's only in one direction; this is in both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $[U^T U]_{ij} = u_i^T u_j $.
 Hence $U^T U = I$ **iff** $u_i^T u_j = \delta_{ij} $ **iff** $u_k$ are orthonormal.